# Randomly picking unique elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, random

I use rand to reach random three element from `a` and add this `m` values to `array` but I want them to be unique. So, array can't be like this: `array = [1,1,2]`. How can I check when two elements are equal and how to prevent this other than sample method? I was thinking about this: Let's assume m=1 when times method runs the first time. If m =1 at the second time, I want to skip this value and reach a different one. Is there any code explanation for this ? Or maybe more different way?

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array = []

3.times do 
  m = a[rand(a.size)]
  array << m 
end
```

Comment: So are you trying to re-implement sample?

Comment: Yes, I want to learn how it works.

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-sample is a good place to start, and has the C source.

Comment: If you want to learn how shuffle is implemented in the standard library, you should edit your question to more clearly reflect that. Right now, looks like you are looking for alternative implementations for shuffle.

Comment: Actually, I am thinking how can I recreate sample with my way and what I wrote is the first thing that came to my mind but I can't really do this myself. It's not just about how sample works but that would be nice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you wish to write a method similar to [Array#sample](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sample), that returns a pseudo-random sample of a given size without replacement. I suggest the following, which I believe would be relatively efficient, particularly when the sample size is small or large relative to the size of array.

```
def sample(arr, sample_size)
  n = arr.size
  raise ArgumentError if n < sample_size
  a = arr.dup
  m = (sample_size < n/2) ? sample_size : n - sample_size      
  m.times do
    i = rand(n)
    n -= 1
    a[i], a[n] = a[n], a[i]
  end
  n = arr.size
  (sample_size < n/2) ? a[n-sample_size..] : a[0, sample_size]
end
```

```
a = [7, 5, 7, 1, 9, 6, 2, 0, 6, 7]
```

Notice that if `sample_size >= arr.size/2` I sample `arr.size - sample_size` elements and return the unsampled elements.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`shuffle`](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array:shuffle) and slice 3 elements:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
shuffled = a.shuffle[0..2]
```